# Why does this override not compile when <T> is present?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, overriding, type-parameter

This override does not compile, but when the type parameter T is removed from the overriding method it compiles fine. Why?

```
class Base {

    public <T> Collection<String> transform(Collection<String> list) {
        return null;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public <T> Collection<String> transform(Collection list) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot <String> in parameter of the overriding method.

Comment: That use of `<T>` in that method signature makes no sense and adds nothing, as T isn't used.

Comment: Thanks for the replies:) I left out <String> on purpose because it compiles fine when <T> is not there in the overriding method, but does not compile when <T> is there. I was just wondering why the introduction of <T> in the overriding method makes it not compile. And yes, I could have used the T, but I left it unused for clarity. Even if I used the T in the return I would have the same question: why doesn't it compile, while without <T> it does?

Comment: ////////// @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 0):

You forgot Collection in the method parameter.

Version that may be compiled:

```java
class Base {

        public <T> Collection<String> transform(Collection<String> list) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    class Derived extends Base {
        @Override
        // Here
        public <T> Collection<String> transform(Collection<String> list) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I left out <String> on purpose, because as far as I know the parameter in the overriding method can erase the type (that is why it compiles fine when <T> is removed). What I was wondering was why the <T> makes it not compile?

Comment: Hi, maybe there is something I'm missing here, but by the same logic this should not compile, but it does: ```class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public Collection<String> transform(Collection list) {
        return null;
    }

}```

Comment: No idea then why it works like that, cannot find any info